# I want when I click this button to be directed to another action method in another controller

Tags: html, razor, knockout.js

the state is as follow: I have a razor page and knockout View model I have a button like this:

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-icon fill d-prt-none" data-bind="visible:$root.bookable,attr: { id: 'addToBasket-btn_'+$index(), }"><i class="mz-shop mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Book</span></button>
```

and the view model with knockout is something like that:

```js
export default class EventDetails {
  constructor(options, eventKey) {
    this.Options = Object.assign({}, options);
    this.Event = ko.observable();
    this.EventAvalibality = ko.observable(null);

    this.basketUtil = new BasketTitleUtil(options);
    this.basketUtil.maxAmount = 10;
    if (options.loadNotepads) {
      this.notepads = new NotepadsViewModel({
        apiBaseUrl: options.apiBaseUrl,
        apiToken: options.apiToken
      });
    } else {
      this.notepads = {};
    }

    // computed values
    this.showLoading = ko.computed(function() {
      return this.EventAvalibality() == null;
    }, this);
    this.avaIndecator = ko.computed(function() {
      if (this.EventAvalibality()) {
        return this.MapAvailabilityIndectror(this.EventAvalibality().EventAvailablility());
      }
    }, this);
    this.bookable = ko.computed(function() {
      let result = false;
      if (this.EventAvalibality()) {
        result = this.EventAvalibality().EventAvailablility() == 0 || this.EventAvalibality().EventAvailablility() == 1;
      }
      return result;
    }, this);
    this.avalibialityLoaded = ko.computed(function() {
      return this.EventAvalibality() != null;
    }, this);
    this.maxSeats = ko.computed(function() {
      if (this.avalibialityLoaded()) {
        if (this.EventAvalibality().FreePlaces() > 10)
          return 10;
        else
          return this.EventAvalibality().FreePlaces();
      }
    }, this);

    this.Init(eventKey);
  }


  formatCurrency = (amount) => {
    console.log(amount);
    var formatOptiopns = {
      'decimal': ',',
      'grouping': '.',
      'fraction': 2,
      'prefix': '',
      'suffix': ''
    };
    return CurrencyFormatter.format(parseFloat(amount), formatOptiopns)
  }

  CheckAvalibality = (e) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.Options.apiBaseUrl + "/api/products/events/availability/" + this.Event().EventKey(), // counter IE hard caching
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer' + this.Options.apiToken
      },
      beforeSend: () => {
        this.ShowBtnLoading($("#check-availability"), "white");
      },
      success: response => {
        this.RemoveBtnLoading($("#check-availability"), "<i class='mz-shop mr-1' aria-hidden='true'></i><span> Verfügbarkeit abrufen");
        let vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(response);
        this.EventAvalibality(vm);
      }
    });
  }

  MapAvailabilityIndectror = avaCode => {
    let result = {};
    if (avaCode < 2)
      result["av-" + avaCode] = true;
    else
      result["av-2"] = true;
    return result;
  }

  Init(eventKey) {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.Options.apiBaseUrl + "/api/search/details/event/" + eventKey + '?v=' + Date.now(), // counter IE hard caching
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer' + this.Options.apiToken
      },
      success: response => {
        let vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(response);
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // MOCK
        vm.MANZ_Contact = ko.mapping.fromJS({
          "FirstName": "Barbara",
          "LastName": "Krenn",
          "TitlePrefix": "Mag.",
          "TitleSuffix": null,
          "Phone": "+43 1 xxxxx",
          "EMail": "bkr@manz.at"
        });
        vm.Availability = ko.mapping.fromJS({
          "AvailabilityState": null,
          "AvailabilityText": "Verfügbarkeit unbekannt"
        });
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if (vm.Prices) {
          vm.Prices = {
            StandardPrice: vm.Prices().find(item => item.Type() === 'Voll'),
            ReducedPrice: vm.Prices().find(item => item.Type() === 'Reduziert'),
            PriceOptions: vm.Prices().filter(item => item.Type() === 'Spezial')
          };

          for (let key in vm.Prices) {
            if ($.isArray(vm.Prices[key])) {
              vm.Prices[key].forEach(price => this.CreatePriceSummary(price));
            } else {
              this.CreatePriceSummary(vm.Prices[key]);
            }
          }
        }

        if (vm.Moderators) {
          for (let moderator of Common.parseFunction(vm.Moderators)) {
            moderator.FullName = ko.computed(() => [
              Common.parseFunction(moderator.Salutation_Prefix),
              Common.parseFunction(moderator.FirstName),
              Common.parseFunction(moderator.LastName),
              Common.parseFunction(moderator.Salutation_Suffix)
            ].join(' ').trim());
            moderator.ImageUrl(Common.parseFunction(moderator.ImageUrl) || '/images/noPortrait.svg');
            moderator.Description(Common.parseFunction(moderator.Description) || '<strong>' + Common.parseFunction(moderator.FullName) + '</strong> ist lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.')
          }
        }
        vm.BasketAmount = ko.observable(1);
        vm.CoverLink = ko.observable(null);
        vm.CoverThumbnails = ko.observable(null);
        this.Event(vm);
        $("#check-availability").click();
      }
    });
  }

  CreatePriceSummary(price) {
    return price ? price.PriceSummary = ko.computed(() => Common.currency.format(Common.parseFunction(price.Amount)).replace('EUR', '')) : '';
  }

  ShowErrorDetails(elem) {
    let msg = '<ul><li class="error">' + elem.OnixValidationErrors().join('</li><li class="error">') + '</li></ul>';
    if (elem.OnixErrors()) {
      msg = '<ul><li class="error">' + $.map(elem.OnixErrors(), function(error) {
        return error.Error() + ' <strong>(' + error.LineNumber() + ':' + error.LinePosition() + ')</strong>';
      }).join('</li><li class="error">') + '</li></ul>';
    }
    new Dialog('.modal', {
      type: 'error',
      size: 'large',
      title: "ONIX-Fehler Details",
      message: msg
    });
  }

  ShowMediaFile(item, evt) {
    new Dialog('#reader', {
      size: 'xlarge',
      remove: false
    });
    var frame = "";
    try {
      var Link = Common.parseFunction(item.Url);
      frame = !/(?:jpe?g|gif|tiff)/.test(Link) ? '<object type="application/pdf" data="' + Link + '" style="width: 100%; height: 850px; max-height: 100%;" />' : '<img class="img-fluid" src="' + Link + '" />';
      if (/(?:jpe?g|gif|tiff)/.test(Link)) {
        $('#readerWidget').css({
          overflow: 'auto'
        });
      }
      $('#readerWidget').html($(frame));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  ShowBtnLoading(btn, color) {
    var currentWidth = btn.css("width");
    var currentHeight = btn.css("height");

    // disable button
    btn.attr("disabled", true);

    // show loading
    btn.text("");
    btn.css("height", currentHeight);
    btn.css("width", currentWidth);
    btn.css("background-position", "50% 50%");
    btn.css("background-repeat", "no-repeat");
    btn.css("background-size", "24px");

    switch (color.toLowerCase()) {
      case "white":
        btn.css("background-image", "url(/icons/loading-spinner.svg)");
        break;
      case "red":
        btn.css("background-image", "url(/icons/loading-spinner.svg)");
        break;
    }
  }

  RemoveBtnLoading(btn, txt) {
    btn.css("background-image", "none");
    btn.attr("disabled", false);
    btn.html(txt);
  }

}

window.EventDetails = EventDetails;
```

what I want to achieve is when I click on the button I redirected to another action method, I tried something like that:

```html
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-icon fill d-prt-none" data-bind="visible:$root.bookable,attr: { href:'/checkout/events/' + eventKey + '?seats=' + BasketAmount, id: 'addToBasket-btn_'+$index(), }"><i class="mz-shop mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Book</span></a>
```

but it does not work, any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the `href` attribute get rendered exactly as you'd expect?

Comment: What happens when you click on the link?  WHat does the rendered markup of the anchor tag look like?